# form checkout template file in avada theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’d like to edit the "checkout" default WooCommerce form (fields like : billing address, first name, second name...etc.), but woocommerce template file form-checkout.php is not present in Avada Theme; other template files in woocommerce/checkout folder does not contain code for checkout form generating.

Where can I find template or define new custom template for checkout form in Avada?

Comment: You should search just a little, see this Official documentation: [Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

Comment: Yes, I know about that, but I need to customize, for example, HTML tags like in original „form-checkout.php” file: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php

Comment: In this case you can [customize/override WC templates via your child theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)…

Comment: It would be perfect to simply override file, but unfortunately I didn’t find any file that would be overrided – child theme with „form-checkout.php” template in this case is simply useless because of lack „parent” file.

Comment: This is quite complicated and needs to be done in the hooks you will find in here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_form_field.html#1841-2061

Comment: Ok, thank you – linked documentation is obsolete (for woocommerce 2.5), but it gave me a huge hint: how function is called. Now I know everything I wanted :)

P.S. I don’t know how to give you a reputation point :(

Comment: The docs are not obsolete, they have been maid under WC version 2.5, and they are still compatible with actual WC version.You can't for the moment, you should need at least 15 points of reputation yourself… Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the exact file you may need to edit is  **form-billing.php** which is under **woocommerce** folder,the relative path not the form-checkout.php :

..\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\checkout\form-billing.php

you could edit this file in your child-theme by following these steps:
https://www.dreamhost.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-woocommerce-child-theme/